# Using JBoss Cache as directory for Apache Lucene

Tags: java, caching, jboss, lucene, directory

Has anyone tried to store Lucene index in JBoss Cache? Are there any good implementations of Lucene Directory for it? I found sources only for [this](http://viewvc.jboss.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/jbosscache/jbosscache-lucene/jbosscache/src/java/org/apache/lucene/store/jbosscache/) one but I can't find any documentation or testimonials on it.

Basically what I would like to do is to store Lucene index in JBoss Cache and manipulate it with application written with GridGain support (GridGain supports JBoss Cache almost out of the box).

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBossCache isn't really suitable as a directory medium for lucene, because it has no facility for file locking, and its atomicity is fuzzy at best. None of this makes for a good consistent index.

You may be interested to know what the Compass Project does (Compass does for Lucene what Hibernate does for JDBC). Compass supports [the storage of the index using a number of 3rd party distribution technologies](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.2.0/reference/html/compass-needle.html), but JBoss Cache isn't one of them. I believe it was tried, and abandoned because it just didn't work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Compass for a long time, and familiar with "needle" (I was using it with Terracotta), but storing really large and constantly changing index in Terracotta can be painful since free version allows only one active server and limits number of stored objects to Integer.MAX_VALUE (at the moment - it can be changed in the future). And of course I don't want to "bind" the system to the static topology.

Also Compass doesn't provide interface to Lucene's HitCollector.

Comment: Have you tried posting on the compass forum? It's pretty good for getting anseers to this sort of thing.